# if a Borel algebra separates points, the topology is $T_0$

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory

Suppose that  $\mathcal{B}(X)$, the Borel algebra generated by the topology $\mathcal{T}$ on $X$, separates points (i.e., for any $x\neq y$, there is some $A\in\mathcal{B}(X)$ such that $x\notin A$ but $y\in A$). Then, how can I conclude that $\mathcal{T}$ is at least $T_0$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\mathcal{T}$ is not $T_0$ then there exist two distinct points $x,y$ such that each open set containing one of these points also contains the other. Then at any step of the transfinite recursive construction of $\mathcal{B}(X)$ from $\mathcal{T}$ we cannot obtain a set which separates points $x$ and $y$.

Answer (score 0):

Or by a monotone class argument: For a fixed pair $x\not= y$ of points of $X$, consider the class $\mathcal S$ of all Borel sets $B$ with the property that either $\{x,y\}\subset B$ or $\{x,y\}\subset B^c$.
Then $\mathcal S$ can be shown to be a $\lambda$-system, and $\mathcal S$ contains the $\pi$-system) $\mathcal T$. Therefore $\mathcal S$ coincides with the Borel sets.